View from a ship with an Alcubierre Drive
What would a person on a ship with an Alcubierre Drive see as the drive starts running and once it is running?  Once the drive is fully powered, the ship would be going faster than light.
I have found the related question What would an external observer see when passed by an Alcubierre drive ship?  It seems from the answers there that the warp bubble does allow light to cross the boundary, but with substantial refraction and wavelength shift effects.  Combine this with the fact that the bubble is moving forwards faster than light, so no photons can hit the bubble from behind.  I think the result is that you get an extremely distorted and wavelength shifted view of the what is in front of the ship, but I assume there are substantial other factors.

Related perhaps: What does the view outside my ship traveling at light speed look like?

A very relevant but not a duplicate question is What does the view outside my ship traveling at light speed look like?. But in your case, we're considering the fanciful and fictional case of FTL. From a practical perspective, the only light you can possibly "see" are the photons directly ahead of you - if you can see those at all. This question might be opinion-based as there is no actual science to draw from to explain what photons might be visible in an FTL context. The best answer might be, "only that which you bring with you."

@JBH
That reasoning pretty much leaves out any question on magic and fantasy.

@JustinThymetheSecond The OP tagged this question [tag:science-based]. There is no science behind a hypothetical technology, much less the consequences of using it. And to forestall an argument, I neither down voted nor VTC'd this question - I'm helping the OP understand a weakness in the question - something we're all supposed to be doing (community moderation).

@JBH
It is my understanding that the 'opinion based' VTC qualification is not based on the question being 'science-based'. But here is the thing- 'science-based' to someone writing sci-fi would be very different depending on when they write the sci-fi, and on how thick the physics textbook was at the time of writing. Someone writing sci-fi in 1850 would have very different 'science-based' answers than someone writing in 1900, 1950, 20000, 2020, and 2024. The physics textbook doubles in thickness what, every ten years or so?

@JustinThymetheSecond The community has never nailed down a consistent interpretation of "opinion-based." Personally, I only use it when the [help/dont-ask] prohibition against questions leading to all answers having equal value is violated. In other words, the purest form of brainstorming (trivially: what color should my drapes be?). The reason I feel this Q could lead to that is that without a mathematical proof (at least) one answer is no better than another (having equal value). Frankly, as I read the current answers, we've likely achieved that nefarious goal.

@DartWert Narrowminded.... The OP tagged this [tag:science-based], not me, and that tag scopes the answer, not the question. If you think it's unreasonable for that tag to be in play, take it up with the OP.

@
JBH
I am saying that the field of 'science' is so variegated today, that the tag really does not do much to restrict potential answers. In point of truth, it is usually one's OPINION on what 'science' says today that determines 'opinion-based' as pretty much the same as 'science-based'.

They would see stuff normally, albeit blueshifted and distorted, in a cone in front of them.
Drop the speed-of-light stuff; what can the captain of a supersonic aircraft hear? The exact same logic applies: start going faster than the carrier of information, and you can only receive information from a cone in front of you. The shape is roughly related to the shape that the shockwave going behind the supersonic craft has; imagine drawing the shockwave as the standard cone emanating from behind the craft, then rotate it 180.
A lot of those distortion effects are related to the ultra-high energy density of the spacetime as well as the immense curvature, so if you figure out how to build one without breaking quantum mechanical rules, the image would likely be less distorted as we’d expect. Based on some simulations I did a while back, though, you could expect a fisheye effect from inside the bubble, increasing in strength as you speed up. Once you cross $c$, also expect everything behind you to disappear.

Why would the ship see a blue shift? The ship is not moving, space itself is being compressed or stretched at the boundary of the warp bubble. Space inside the buble is flat, and once a photon has crossed the boundary of the buble, it will be dragged along with the space ship, so I would expect colors to be unchanged?

No, the ship is veritably moving. It just so happens that the A-drive causes the (FTL) worldline of the ship to be timelike. There is doppler shift but no gravitational blueshift since the A-drive is specifically parameterized as $g_{tt}=\alpha^2c^2=c^2=$that of flat space. I actually study this subject specifically; the compression/stretching of space is not actually a requirement of the A-drive to work (see Natario et. al. who designed equivalent drives sans expansion).

Are you referring to Warp Drive With Zero Expansion by José Natário (doi:10.1088/0264-9381/19/6/308)? There's no "et al", but it looks like the canonical reference.

That is what I’m referring to. I’ve seen the work reproduced a couple other times, but he was the one who originally published on it.

@controlgroup
So in all of that, without expansion/contraction, exactly what 'propels' the bubble through space/time? Seems to be that all you have in the end is a 'bubble' of it's own space/time 'floating' in normal space/time. Really, there appears to be an unstated assumption 'assume a propulsion system'.

@JustinThymetheSecond You seem to be misunderstanding how the drive actually works. There is no physical "bubble", that's just an arbitrary sphere we draw around a region where a particular curvature dominates. You can have the bubble move in any direction along any lightlike worldline; the expansion and contraction are just artifacts of the way Alcubierre originally posed the interesting curvature, not of anything else. Specially-arranged superextremal black holes also work as warp drives, and you'd have no issue stating that there is no contraction/expansion in those spacetimes.

@controlgroup
So black holes travel faster than the speed of light? Again, what causes the bubble to move FTL, except an assumption?

No, but super-extremal black holes allow access to an interior region where there are worldlines with $v>299792458$. And like I said: the "bubble" is not a physical thing moving on a worldlines. Have you read Alcubierre's paper?

@
controlgroup
Reading "Alcubierre's paper" is like reading Nostradamus, or perhaps Nietzsche. Everyone who reads it comes away with a different interpretation, and they all think their interpretation is the correct one..

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sometimes genuine worldbuilding questions need explicitly writing advice answers. I guess this is a frame challenge.
What you want is a widget for shortening travel times that fits the tone of a setting where scientists understand the principles that engineers use to make the tools that characters use, not a doctoral thesis on speculative physics with a story glued to it.
To get a plausible FTL technology, you need a black box plus the declaration that inside the black box is a machine that works because modern physics was a little bit incorrect in a complicated way. You can make up a name for the way that modern physics was incorrect if you want, and you can name the black box for something in modern physics (like Alcubierre) if you want.
The blacker the black box, the better your plausibility. So don't put windows on the space ship, or shutter them for FTL for extra radiation protection. They don't have anything close enough to look at, anyway. Characters can look at computer projections of where things effectively are. (The computer projections run on another black box.)

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It depends on the construction of your drive
The acceleration of the ship in an Alcubierre bubble is due to the compression of spacetime ahead of it. It is equivalent to that of falling into a gravity well. Consider how that spacetime compression is being achieved and we can speculate as to what the view from inside would look like.
Proposals for such a drive fall into two major categories: Wormholes and Tachyons. While you don't have to be specific with your story, the mechanics would affect the shape of your light cones.

Moreover, according to Serguei Krasnikov,[19] generating a bubble in a previously flat space for a one-way faster-than-light trip requires forcing the exotic matter to move at local faster-than-light speeds, something that would require the existence of tachyons

Additionally, regarding the Alcubierre metric, there are choices to be made as well. Does spacetime unfold behind the ship or in another direction?

An extension of the Alcubierre metric that eliminates the expansion of the volume elements and instead relies on the change in distances along the direction of travel is that of mathematician José Natário. In his metric, spacetime contracts towards the prow of the ship and expands in the direction perpendicular to the motion, meaning that the bubble actually "slides" through space, roughly speaking by "pushing space aside".[9][10]

It follows that we must consider the nature of the compressed spacetime ahead of the ship. Do the geodesic lines diverge out? Only light traveling through the spacetime that is shared with the ship can be seen from the ship.
Wormholes: In this case, a spacetime fold exists (naturally or artificially) in the corridor between your ship and its destination. Light from the far end should be visible normally as you would see looking through a tube.  However, you can choose whether the metric allows light to enter the tunnel through the sides or not. If so, it would probably have similar effects as Gravitational Lensing.
Tachyons: In order to fold spacetime ahead of the ship superluminally, something must trave ahead, faster than the speed of light, to deliver the energy required to compress spacetime. Here, all bets are off as tachyons are purely hypothetical and their effects are as well. Is there a Naked singularity ahead of your ship or did your drive produce an event horizon? You could make a case for seeing nothing but black, or bright white as light is distorted by the compressed spacetime ahead.
So to answer your question and give a suggestion: As others have pointed out, writing a dissertation into the story is not ideal. It requires a level of understanding from readers that is really not necessary. As all effects on light seen from an Alcubierre driven ship are hypothetical, pick one, give a short explanation, and your readers will accept it.

An Alcubierre drive bubble is less complex than people think it is. It compresses space in the volume in front of the ship, and de-compresses it behind the ship. This means that, at the same velocity, the ship moves across a greater amount of space.
If you follow that math, another implication is that the volume inside the warp bubble is a medium of higher density than the surrounding space. Fortunately, thanks to Willebrord Snellius, we know exactly how light behaves when passing through a denser medium. Just consider the volume inside of the bubble to be like a bubble of water in air, adjusting for density as a percentage of the speed of light.
The thing I never really got about an Alcubierre drive is what makes them think that the laws of time dilation would be changed. Unless you have some other magic, then you're still going to see normal relativistic blue-shifting of light. If you do have that magic, then you won't.
BUT there will be more of it. A lot more. This is the "running through raindrops" concept. When figuring out how wet you'll get when running through rain, the amount of wet you get doesn't change much if you move faster.
That calculation, however, is based on passing through a fixed volume. Same volume = same wet. This changes if you consider it from the perspective of wet per second. When running, you collect all of the wet in a shorter period of time.
When moving through rain, your exposure to water is a function of your speed compared to the speed of falling raindrops (which, like the speed of light, can be considered a constant). Here's the Wolfram Alpha page on those calculations. You just have to substitute "bright" for "wet".

Not sure why this got downvoted, this is a perfectly reasonable answer. As far as time dilation, you should note that kinematic time dilation stops happening inside an Alcubierre drive.

@controlgroup, people get protective of their perspective on relativity. My understanding is that time dilation is an artifact of passing through space-time, not specifically of velocity. That's why general relativity works. I just don't think anyone's done the calculations on Alcubierre space. Maybe time dilation is reversed, and you age faster compared to the outside world? Dunno.

Oh, the calculations on Alcubierre spacetime have been done plenty of times. The reason it works is that $\gamma=1$ inside the warp bubble no matter what velocity is. Time dilation is most definitely an artifact of the geometry of spacetime; in flat spacetime, the Lorentz factor goes up with velocity, but inside an A-drive, spacetime isn't curved in that way. You age the same rate inside as anyone anywhere.

It got downvotet because its making statements about alcubiere drives and spacetime and at the same time the author admits he's not getting it. That makes it kind of worthless for a science-based question. Also the rain analog falls short because you don't ride through rain in a spacetime bubble that will affect the raindrops before hitting you.

@controlgroup, "You age the same rate inside as anyone anywhere" Not gonna complain, but that sounds like you are a proponent of the universal now.

@RobertRapplean Not all spacetime metrics obey translational/velocity symmetry. For example the Schwarzschild spacetime is only valid in the rest frame of the black hole. Try calculating $\gamma$ yourself given the Alcubierre metric where $f(r_s)\approx 1$ and find that it is independent of velocity relative to anything.

When 'running through raindrops' problem is considered, one has to be concerned with the direction the rain is falling. Straight down, towards the runner, away from the runner, or from the side of the runner? Same with 'time' and the A-drive. Are you considering present time future time, or past time? What happens in the 'future' is not so 'future' the faster you move towards it.

@JustinThymetheSecond, The Wolfram Alpha page includes angle of the rain, but presumes that particles that obey the exclusion principal, which light does not. You can generalize it as light coming from all directions at once, but can get more specific about point sources like the star you're headed for. Time dilation would only make the rate worse.

Here's the thing. When describing the action of raindrops, it is pretty much assumed that they are not going to be deflected around the body without any opportunity to actually connect with it and get it wet. That assumption can not be assumed when talking about light and the A-drive. Will light follow a 'straight line', or will it be warped around the A-drive vehicle by the warping of space/time involved?

@JustinThymetheSecond, I'm pretty sure I gave my answer to that in the main body.

I am not sure that someone inside the bubble would 'see' anything from the outside at all.
As I understand it, the entire concept of the A-drive is to 'warp' space/time around the bubble, therefore everything including photons would be warped around the bubble as well. For anything from the outside to be 'seen' from the inside, something from the outside would have to be left behind. Not quite sure how that would be handled by physics and that 'conservation of energy and momentum transfer' thing.
Seems to me an A-drive bubble would be the perfect cloaking device, with the Law of Unintended Consequences requiring that not only can the outside not see the cloaked device, but the cloaked device can not by definition detect anything from the outside. To detect anything from the outside, something from the outside would have to be 'left behind' on the inside, thus would result in a 'void' or shadow when 'seen' from the outside.
An even more interesting conjecture would be 'how would entanglement between the inside and the outside' work?

The result can be anything you want for story purposes. An actual Alcubierre drive traveling faster than light would break physics. Relativity, causality and a lot more beside would need to be rewritten to account for the new phenomena.
In such cases there would be little point in asking what the old broken physics predicts because it would clearly be wrong.
It is a bit like asking what does spherical geometry predict about what is north of the North Pole? If someone actually demonstrated such a place, spherical geometry as we know it would be shown to have a flaw and it would have no predictive power concerning such places.
No doubt people will have a range of speculative views one what happens. I would use whichever one fits your purposes best.

The absolute bottom-line truth is that we now know with almost certainty that 'Relativity, causality and a lot more beside' are already 'broken' by observed reality, and such issues should never have to be considered in modern science fiction.
